# why free command say different from the real consuming memory

Tags: rhel, kernel, memory, vmware, free

from our linux VM rhel 7.5 server with 126G memory

we have strange memory behavior that consume all available memory  as the following

```
free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            126         122           0           1           2       1        
Swap:           10           10           0
```

we have bash script that calculate exactly the consuming of memory and this are the results

```
  5.2 MiB +   2.3 MiB =   7.6 MiB       sshd (4)
 10.2 MiB + 159.0 KiB =  10.4 MiB       polkitd
 12.6 MiB + 315.0 KiB =  12.9 MiB       gsd-color
 16.6 MiB +   5.0 KiB =  16.6 MiB       node_exporter
 11.3 MiB +  27.1 MiB =  38.4 MiB       systemd-journald
 40.4 MiB +  15.9 MiB =  56.3 MiB       rsyslogd
 73.3 MiB +   1.4 MiB =  74.7 MiB       python2.7 (3)
226.4 MiB +   2.7 MiB = 229.2 MiB       gnome-shell
  1.4 GiB +   1.1 MiB =   1.4 GiB       df.pll
 15.7 GiB +   9.2 MiB =  15.7 GiB       java (9)
 22.1 GiB +   2.0 MiB =  22.1 GiB       KLP-server

---------------------------------
                         39.6 GiB
```

and from the `top` command we can see that memory actually consume around `40G`

so how it can be that we see from `free -g` only `1G` available?

what we can see also
is that:

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
81632 MB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon
81632 MB
```

is the answer: your system is using approximately 40GiB of memory, and 80GiB are reserved by the VMware ballooning mechanism, resulting in the 122GiB “used” reported by `free`.

The memory reserved by the balloon isn’t consumed by a process, so it doesn’t appear in `ps` or `top`’s output.

Comment: so do we need to be worry if available memory from free -g is almost 0 , I don’t sure if some process need additional memory and it take it from the memory_balloon ?? , so I not sure what we can do in this stage , this is very critical production server , and we worry that alll application will fail because the memory problem

Comment: second how we can decrease the memory_balloon from the Vcenter?  , can we do it without shutdown the VM machine ?

Comment: If the VM *host* has memory available, the balloon should deflate on its own if processes in a VM try to use more memory. If you’re seeing swap use and ballooning, it’s a pretty good indicator that your host is over-subscribed.

Comment: based on what you said , I think to do the following test on all VM machines , for example when vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon value is more then 30% then memory machine then it will give alert about this , what you think about this test?